# Do not show again checkbox on a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

So the title explains it all. I have a dialogfragment that currently pops up and I want to add a do not show checkbox to it and then obviously implement that check and not show if it was checked. I know there is a .setSingleChoiceItems, but I am not entirely sure on what would be going in there as it isn't really an item I would add somewhere. But then again I could probably be wrong as I am just getting into Android development.

Dialogfragment java

```
public class WifivsDataDialog extends DialogFragment {


     @
     Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
         builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_box)
             .setPositiveButton(R.string.WiFi, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     // FIRE ZE MISSILES!

                 }
             })
             .setNegativeButton(R.string.Cell_Data, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     // User cancelled the dialog
                 }
             });
         // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
         return builder.create();
     }
 }
```

Here is the code calling it in my MainActivity.java

```
 WifivsDataDialog myDiag = new WifivsDataDialog();
    myDiag.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog_layout");
    myDiag.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: What you want to say...... Actual It is working..... Dialog

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini I am not sure I follow? The dialog currently pops up when I start the app. Do I do anything based on the option selected yet? No because I have to say if user picks WiFi only use WiFi and if they select data only use Data to start my oAuth2

Comment: Take the custom layout to dialog of checkbox and Take two check box in layout when click on anyone than set enable wifi or mobie data on other

Comment: Ok, got that part. What about adding a do not show again checkbox to my dialogfragment?

Comment: Check the condtion if wifi enable than hide wificheckbox and when mobiledata enable than checkbox mobile hide Other wise both show

Comment: Wait, I don't think you are understanding the question. Because if I check if wifi is enabled, if they are downloading the app via wifi and they open it, the dialog box wouldn't pop up. So I want the dialog box to pop up regardless of connection type and then be able to check the "Do not show again" checkbox and have the popup not show again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DialogFragment class

```
    public class WifivsDataDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wifi_dialog, container);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) mainView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        button1 = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                // Store the isChecked to Preference here
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", isChecked);
                editor.commit();

            }
        });
        return mainView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                // Do wifi stuff here
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                // Do cellular stuff here
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Layout xml wifi_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="20dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some information to be displayed to human"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="30dp"/>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Do now show this dialog again."
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WiFi"
                android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CELL"
                android:id="@+id/button2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And on your Activity or where ever you display the dialog, check the preference set by user before displaying the dialog. Something like below.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean dontShowDialog = sharedPref.getBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", false);
        if (!dontShowDialog) {
            new WifivsDataDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "WiFi");
        }
```

Comment: is it possible to add this to what I currently have? I wanted to leave the buttons as WiFi and Cell Data (4G) along with the checkbox. Not entirely sure if it is or not. Because I want the user to choose between WiFi or 4G and then enable whichever one they pick if it isn't enabled.

Comment: if you can do that, you will be a god among men haha

Comment: You can add any number of buttons you want in the layout file and handle accordingly. I have edited the code above.

Comment: The man the myth the legend! And then I just need to put dismiss(); in the case to close the box. Do you happen to know how to revert the whole checked box thing for testing purposes? Haha

Comment: :-) Just comment all the checkbox code in WifivsDataDialog or comment below linesSharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", isChecked);
                editor.commit();

Comment: Hmm ok :) well I tested on the emulator and the checkbox works haha. I know this is off topic but do you happen to know why 

`WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)` `getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);`
                `wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);`

Says "Cannot resolve method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)'"

I am putting this within the case R.if.button1

Comment: You need to call getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: Beautiful! I tried doing that but with telephonymanager, but didn't have any success

Comment: I have looked around and I haven't found anything about if the user checks do not show again only use the connection type they picked. Any ideas on that? Along with the turning cell phone data on?

Comment: in the switch statement, can I copy the sharedpreferences from the onCheckChange?

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works, but it doesn't look like the normal material design system dialog, which is what I wanted.

Here's an option using a custom view layout to hold just the text and checkbox (with padding that matches material design), and allow the AlertDialog to manage the buttons.

`no_location_dialog.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_location_text"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:text="@string/main_nolocation"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"></TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/location_never_ask_again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_never_ask_again" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code for setting up the AlertDialog:

```
private Dialog createNoLocationDialog() {
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.no_location_dialog, null);
    CheckBox neverShowDialog = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.location_never_ask_again);

    neverShowDialog.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        // Save the preference
        PreferenceUtils.saveBoolean(getString(R.string.preference_key_never_show_location_dialog), isChecked);
        }
    });

    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(icon, getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_primary));

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle(R.string.main_nolocation_title)
        .setIcon(icon)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setView(view)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.rt_yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivityForResult(
                                new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                                REQUEST_NO_LOCATION);
                    }
                }
        )
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.rt_no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Ok, I suppose we can just try looking from where we
                        // are.
                        mMapFragment.mController.onLocation();
                    }
                }
        );
    return builder.create();
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Here's the full code in a commit on Github - https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/commit/98135b66b0be5b73187e0148bef5d308c42a9fbe.